# The cofiber sequence $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^n\to S^{2n}$

Tags: homology-cohomology, projective-space, orientation

$\newcommand{\CP}{\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$*(Let the notation $H^*(X)$ represent $H^*(X;\Z)$, i.e. ordinary unreduced cohomology with $\Z$ coefficients.)*

The standard inclusion $\CP^{n-1}\hookrightarrow\CP^{n}$ induces a cofiber sequence
$$\CP^{n-1}\longrightarrow\CP^{n}\longrightarrow S^{2n}$$
Since the connecting homomorphisms are trivial, there is a short exact sequence corresponding to this,
$$0\longrightarrow H^{2n}(S^{2n}) \longrightarrow H^{2n}(\CP^{n})\longrightarrow H^{2n}(\CP^{n-1})\longrightarrow 0$$
The cohomology ring $H^*(\CP^k)$ is isomorphic to $\Z[x]/(x^{k+1})$ with $|x|=2$, so this is just the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow \Z\longrightarrow \Z\longrightarrow 0\longrightarrow 0$$
with the middle $\Z$ being the subgroup of $\Z[x]/(x^{n+1})$ generated by the multiples of $x^n$.

It seems only reasonable to assume that the image of $1\in\Z\cong H^{2n}(S^{2n})$ is the element $x^n\in H^{2n}(\CP^{n+1})$, but **how do we know its image is not $-x^n$?**

(In fact, I'm a little unclear on whether there is a canonical choice of an element $1$ in $H^{2n}(S^{2n})$, and similarly, if there is a canonical choice of element $x$ in $H^2(\CP^n)$. Does this have something to do with orientations?)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The statements you've written down are true for unreduced cohomology, not reduced cohomology.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for catching that, I made the edit now.